# SQL Server Stored Procedure, View and Table Unique Identifier

Tags: sql-server

Where does SQL Server save its unique identifier for stored procedures, views and tables? When I rename a stored procedure, how does SQL Server know what stored procedure to rename?

I'm hoping it's something like a row number that I can select in a query. By looking at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, I'm able to get a table of objects but can't figure out how SQL Server keeps track of any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you are talking about `object_id`. `SELECT * FROM sys.objects` has all objects and their ID's

You can also do:

```
select OBJECT_ID('your_proc_name_here')
```

to see what the object_id is.

As for tracking changes, there is not a table that keeps what your proc was prior to an alter statement or tells you what the view definition was 2 weeks ago. You would have to make a user defined table and write logic to handle that, or use a VCS.